# Trouble passing static string as REGEXP with csplit

Tags: linux, terminal, csplit

I'm on a Linux terminal and struggling to split a large text file into several smaller files. I'm trying with `csplit`, but `csplit` demands that the delimiter pattern is passed as a REGEXP. The static delimiter pattern is `, lorum ipsum`. How do I write that as a REGEXP? After reading a bit, I would expect `/'^, lorum ipsum$'/` to work, but it does not. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it worked for you, or, if it didn't, let us know the details.

Comment: I will when I can! I haven't had access to a computer since I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/', lorum ipsum'/`, `^` and `$` is start and end of the line accordingly, which is not needed in your case.